# Python - How to wait on both queue and a socket on same time

Tags: python

I want to read messages from either a Queue.Queue or a TCP socket, whichever comes first.
How can it be achieved without resorting to 2 threads ?
Platform is CPython 2.7.5 on Windows

Comment: You can't... easily. Something like `select(2)` would work for two blocking sockets, but not for a `Queue`. The closest you could get would be to use non-blocking methods in a loop, if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in a single thread, you'll have to use non-blocking methods, and merge them into a single event loop. I'm actually using `select` instead of non-blocking socket I/O here, since it's slightly cleaner if you need to read from multiple sockets...

```
import socket
import select
import Queue
import time

TIMEOUT = 0.1   # 100ms


def process_queue_item(item):
    print 'Got queue item: %r' % item


def process_socket_data(data):
    print 'Got socket data: %r' % data


def main():

    # Build queue
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        queue.put(i)
    queue.put(None)   # Using None to indicate no more data on queue
    queue_active = True

    # Build socket
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
    sock.send('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
    socket_active = True

    # Main event loop
    while 1:

        # If there's nothing to read, bail out
        if not (socket_active or queue_active):
            break

        # By default, sleep at the end of the loop
        do_sleep = True

        # Get data from socket without blocking if possible
        if socket_active:
            r, w, x = select.select([sock], [], [], TIMEOUT)
            if r:
                data = sock.recv(64)
                if not data:    # Hit EOF
                    socket_active = False
                else:
                    do_sleep = False
                    process_socket_data(data)

        # Get item from queue without blocking if possible
        if queue_active:
            try:
                item = queue.get_nowait()
                if item is None:  # Hit end of queue
                    queue_active = False
                else:
                    do_sleep = False
                    process_queue_item(item)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

        # If we didn't get anything on this loop, sleep for a bit so we
        # don't max out CPU time
        if do_sleep:
            time.sleep(TIMEOUT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output looks like...

```
Got socket data: 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation: http://www.google.co.uk/\r\nCache-Co'
Got queue item: 0
Got socket data: 'ntrol: private\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nSet-Cook'
Got queue item: 1
Got socket data: 'ie: PREF=ID=a192ab09b4c13176:FF=0:TM=1373055330:LM=1373055330:S='
Got queue item: 2
etc.
```

Comment: Iterate 10 times per second or so and poll for both..Not very efficient but I guess there is no other way. How about using 2 threads and pushing the data to a single Queue ? Would it be a better way?

Comment: @GabiMe You can adjust the `TIMEOUT` value to taste. If you're prepared to use multiple threads, there are lots of options. If each thread can handle its own received data, then I'd just put each blocking call in its own thread.

Answer (score 16):

There is a very nice trick to do this [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch12.html#_solution_209) that applies to your problem.

```
import queue
import socket
import os

class PollableQueue(queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Create a pair of connected sockets
        if os.name == 'posix':
            self._putsocket, self._getsocket = socket.socketpair()
        else:
            # Compatibility on non-POSIX systems
            server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
            server.listen(1)
            self._putsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self._putsocket.connect(server.getsockname())
            self._getsocket, _ = server.accept()
            server.close()

    def fileno(self):
        return self._getsocket.fileno()

    def put(self, item):
        super().put(item)
        self._putsocket.send(b'x')

    def get(self):
        self._getsocket.recv(1)
        return super().get()
```

Comment: the link above is dead - here's a new one: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f7wGeA71_eUC&pg=PA532&lpg=PA532&dq=class+PollableQueue(queue.Queue):&source=bl&ots=Xjj50am-Nm&sig=ACfU3U2Haln-bB8QBoKdawco07pm0pIN-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqvfuw36rmAhXIQkEAHX_GDjAQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=class%20PollableQueue(queue.Queue)%3A&f=false The gist of the solution is to write to a queue and a single byte to a socket pair. The other end of the socket pair then indicates data is ready to read, so you read the socket and the queue (the socket provides a semaphore to tell you to read the queue).

Comment: Looks nice, but causes a problem on Linux, no more than a couple of 100s put calls without gets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72011758/early-hang-up-on-socket-send

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
def check_for_message(queue,socket,sock_accept_size=512):
    socket.setblocking(0)
    while True:
        try:
            sock_msg=socket.recv(sock_accept_size)
        except socket.error:
            """Do stuff if there is no message"""
            sock_msg=None
        try:
            que_msg=queue.get()
        except Queue.Empty:
            """Do stuff if there is no message"""
            que_msg=None
        yield (que_msg,sock_msg)
```

Then you can iterate through it using:

```
for que_message,sock_message in check_for_message(que_instance,socket_instance):
    print que_message,sock_message
```